# Unrecognized selector when using Apptentive: -[ATAppRatingFlow appDidLaunch:viewController:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, apptentive

Calling the following method in the Apptentive API is crashing due to an unrecognized selector.

```
ATAppRatingFlow *ratingFlow = [ATAppRatingFlow sharedRatingFlowWithAppID:kApptentiveAppID];
[ratingFlow appDidLaunch:YES viewController:self.navigationController];
```

Which produces the following error log:

```
*2013-10-03 10:32:08.089 YourApp[39841:a0b] -[ATAppRatingFlow appDidLaunch:viewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc5aee60*
*2013-10-03 10:32:08.144 YourApp[39841:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ATAppRatingFlow appDidLaunch:viewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc5aee60'*
**** First throw call stack:*
*(*
* 0 CoreFoundation 0x0257f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180*
* 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x022ee8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44*
* 2 CoreFoundation 0x0261c903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275*
* 3 CoreFoundation 0x0256f90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous versions of Apptentive used the following 3 methods to show the ratings flow:

```
- (void)appDidLaunch:(BOOL)canPromptForRating viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

- (void)appDidEnterForeground:(BOOL)canPromptForRating viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

- (void)userDidPerformSignificantEvent:(BOOL)canPromptForRating viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

They have been replacedby a single method in newer versions of the app:

```
- (void)showRatingFlowFromViewControllerIfConditionsAreMet:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Call it like so:

```
[[ATAppRatingFlow sharedRatingFlow] showRatingFlowFromViewControllerIfConditionsAreMet:viewController];
```

The `showRatingFlowFromViewControllerIfConditionsAreMet` method will *only* show the ratings flow if your rating conditions (as set on the Apptentive website) have been met at that point by the user.

- **X** days after install
- **Y** number of uses
- **Z** significant events